# How to pass bitsets with different sizes to a function?

Tags: c++, std-bitset

I want to pass bitsets to a function. What `size` should I assign to the bitset parameter `bits` in the function prototype if the bitsets have different sizes?

For example:

```cpp
bitset<3> a;
bitset<4> b;

void ABC(bitset<size> bits){
    ...
}

ABC(a);
ABC(b);
```

Comment: 42, obviously..

Comment: How long is _your_ bitset?

Comment: If you're not sure, you can either use a different container that supports runtime-variable size (e.g. `vector<bool>`, `boost::dynamic_bitset`), or make ABC a template ala `template <size_t N> void ABC(std::bitset<N>& a) ...` so it will get instantiated for each distinct size of callers' bitsets.

Comment: actually it should be 43, 42 is deprecated

Answer (score 8):

You can [templatize](http://ideone.com/9A7swP) the function taking bitset as argument.

```
template <size_t bitsetsize>
void ABC(bitset<bitsetsize> a) {
   ...
}
```

This templatized function would be generated by compiler only when you use it somewhere in your code. If you use this function for bitsets of different sizes, separate functions would be instantiated for once for each size. So you should take care to avoid code depending on any local state variables (`static` variables local to function) as the function instances are different.

It is advisable to use a reference or constant reference to avoid object copy.

```
template <size_t bitsetsize>
void ABC(const bitset<bitsetsize> &a) {
   ...
}
```

An alternative which **may not** be fit for your requirements is to use `std::vector<bool>` instead of `std::bitset` if possible.

Comment: This doesn't help, you're adding one more layer of template over `std::bitset`, which again depends on compile-time constant

Comment: Size of `std::bitset` is anyways compile time constant, so compiler would bind the right function at compile time.

Comment: @P0W I think I could not understand your concern.

Comment: So, I was telling what if OP wants to create bitsets at _runtime_ and pass to his/her function ?

Comment: @P0W OK, thanks. My interpretation was, same function accepts bitset from different part of code which may be of different size. What should be the size of bitset in my function argument.

Comment: @Mohit Jain My function compiled fine. But After I added a call to the template function, I got an unresolved external symbol link error. How do you call the function w/o any error? Here is what I did: " bitset<5> bs5; ABC(bs5);"

Comment: @Louis Make sure this template function's definition is available to the caller. If you are using it in just one source file, put the template on top. If you are using template function in multiple files, move it to appropriate header file.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with STL `bitset`.

`std::bitset<N>` template requires a fixed size in advance (at compile-time)

However, one way you can do this by using [*`boost::dynamic_bitset`*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)

---

Something like following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

void ABC(boost::dynamic_bitset<> &a)
{
    /* for (boost::dynamic_bitset<>::size_type i = 0;
            i < a.size(); ++i)
          std::cout << a[i]; */
    std::cout << a << "\n";
}


int main()
{
    std::size_t size= 5; // take any value for 'size' at runtime

    boost::dynamic_bitset<> x(size); // all 0's by default
    x[0] = 1;
    x[1] = 1;
    x[4] = 1;
    ABC( x );

    return 0;
}
```

See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51d60c3eb93dffb0)

Comment: *What* is "not possible"?

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry, I meant the run-time variable `size` for OP's situation with bitset